# Il fut difficile « d'avoir la tache » de café

Tags: sens

Je sais que cette phrase signifie « Il fut difficile d’enlever la tache de café », mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi ; Cette utilisation du verbe  “avoir” ne m’est pas connue. Est-ce que ce sens est spécifique à cette phrase ? Sinon, quelles sont quelques autres phrases avec « avoir » qui ont un sens similaire ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le verbe est bien le verbe "avoir", qui a ici un registre informel (familier, en d'autres mots) et qui signifie « venir à bout de (quelque chose/quelqu'un) », à ne pas confondre avec le verbe familier « avoir » signifiant « tromper (qqn) ».

- C'est un lutteur puissant, mais lui est résistant et à la longue il l'a eu.
- Ce problème demande un travail sans fin mais comme c'est une élève assidue, à force de travail elle l'aura.

Comment: Ah, donc c’est comme si on dit de « remporter/vaincre la tache » ?

Comment: @AtilioA Ce n'est pas idiomatique du tout mais c'est de parfait bon sens.

Comment: Bien sûr, c’est juste un exemple, j'ai trouvé ça drôle parce que en portugais on pourrait dire « vencer/derrotar a mancha » dans un registre informel, pendant que dans l’anglais ça n’est pas commun du tout :)